# Need help in writing the tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver in Tensorflow 2.0.beta1

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to serve my Keras model, but my model is trained on image of shape `(125,125,3)` and it expect an input as numpy array. But as I was learning the `tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver` to pre-process my `b64_enoded` image to a numpy array and feed my model with it, I am stuck here.

All my model building and pre-processing is done in tensorflow 2.0. So I am  looking for a help to write the `tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver` function for it.

Model Summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_a (Conv2D)            (None, 125, 125, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
Activation_a (Activation)    (None, 125, 125, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
MaxPool_a (MaxPooling2D)     (None, 62, 62, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
Conv2d_c (Conv2D)            (None, 62, 62, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
Activation_c (Activation)    (None, 62, 62, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
MaxPool_b (MaxPooling2D)     (None, 31, 31, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
Conv2d_d (Conv2D)            (None, 31, 31, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
Activation_d (Activation)    (None, 31, 31, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
MaxPool_c (MaxPooling2D)     (None, 15, 15, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
Flatten (Flatten)            (None, 28800)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
Dense_a (Dense)              (None, 512)               14746112  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_a (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
Dense_b (Dense)              (None, 512)               262656    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_b (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
output (Dense)               (None, 1)                 513       
=================================================================
Total params: 15,102,529
Trainable params: 15,102,529
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Here is my code :

```py
def build_serving_inputs(inputs):
    def decode_and_resize(image_str_tensor):
        image = tf.io.decode_base64(image_str_tensor)
        image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=3)
        image = tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(image, 125, 125)
        image = image /255
        #image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
        #image = tf.cast(image, dtype=tf.float32)
        return image

    if not isinstance(inputs, np.ndarray):
        inputs = np.array([inputs])

    # Converting the B64 Image data to tensorflow tf.string
    inputs = tf.cast(inputs, tf.string)

    # Decoding the image and returning a numpy array
    decoded_images = tf.map_fn(decode_and_resize, inputs,
        dtype=tf.float32,back_prop=False)
    decoded_images = tf.identity(decoded_images, name="output")
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver()

estimator.export_savedmodel("./model/my_model/",
serving_input_receiver_fn=build_serving_inputs)
```

I want to export my model with the `ServingInput` Receiver as a pre-processing funtion to convert a `b64_encoded` image to numpy and feed it to the Model.